# How to use API code from QRCode-Monkey in simple way?

Tags: html, qr-code

I want to ask about how to use the API code from QRCode-Monkey to generate simple QR Code.
The documentation is just telling you the request URL, method, and body request, without telling us how this is should be performed?

The Request Body is a JSON, where or how should I put them in my simple HTML?

Request URL : /qr/custom 
Request Method : POST
Request Body :

```
{
 "data":"https://www.qrcode-monkey.com",
 "config":{
  "body":"circle",
  "logo":"#facebook"
  },
 "size":300,
 "download":false,
 "file":"svg"
}
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what language you are using.  There is full documentation at https://rapidapi.com/qrcode-monkey/api/custom-qr-code-with-logo

You can either use GET or POST.  Here's a snippet using JavaScript's `fetch`

```
fetch("https://qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com/qr/custom?size=600&file=png&config=%7B%22bodyColor%22%3A%20%22%230277BD%22%2C%20%22body%22%3A%22mosaic%22%7D&data=Hello%20World!", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "YOUR-SECRET-KEY"
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You will need to sign up to RapidAPI to get an API key.